# Broadcasted values from Angular Library Project not getting received

Tags: angular, rxjs, observer-pattern, behaviorsubject, rxjs-observables

I have an angular 12 library project from which I am trying to broadcast some values using behaviorsubject and shared service.

Here is my broadcast service code:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class BroadcastService{
public subject = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

get(){
return this.subject.asObservable();
   }

broadcast(data: any){
     this.subject.next(data);
   }
}
```

}
}

In my sample application which is consuming this angular library project. I am subscribing to this broadcast service in onInit hook using:

```
this.broadcastService.get().subscribe(data => handleData(data) );
```

But only the default value(null) is getting received at subscriber in sample application. Other broadcasted values from library project is not getting received in sample application's component.

When I am debugging .next() method of RxJS it is saying subscriber count is 0.

Comment: when are you calling broadcastService.broadcast ?

Comment: from service inside my library project @SalminSkenderovic

Comment: I don't see any issues in my example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hw4vlj?file=src/broad-cast.service.ts

Comment: you have to run subscription first in ngOninit:   this.broadcastService.get().subscribe((data) => handleData(data));
output: 1 2 3 4